# how to detect source address is IPv4 or IPv6

Tags: rust

Is there any way to detect the source address is IPv4 or IPv6?
I wrote something like

```
let listener = TcpListener::bind("[::]:33333").unwrap();
for res in listener.incoming() {
  match res {
    Ok(stream) => {thread::spawn(move||{handler(stream);},
    Err(_) => {println!("error");},
  }
}
```

The handler function is like:

```
fn handler(mut stream: TcpStream) -> Result<(),Error> {
  if stream.peer_addr().unwrap().is_ipv4() {
    println!("peer is IPv4");
  }
  else {
    println!("peer is IPv6");
  }
```

and in the handler function, I use stream.peer_addr().unwrap().is_ipv4() to find if the peer address is IPv4 or IPv6. But all the addresses are IPv6.  When I connect to the server at 127.0.0.1, the peer address is IPv4-mapped IPv6 address: V6([::ffff:127.0.0.1]:33333).  If the sever binds to 0.0.0.0:33333, I cannot connect to its IPv6 address (for example, ::1).  Is there anyway that the server accepts connections from both IPv4 and IPv6 peers and also not using IPv4-mapped IPv6 address? I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1. Thank you,
eii

Comment: I added listener.set_only_v6(true) but it did not help. It still accepts IPv4-mapped IPv6 address

Comment: Why do you not want to use IPv4-mapped IPv6 address? That's the only compatibility layer provided by your OS. If you want to support both IPv4 and IPv6 without IPv4-mapped IPv6 address, then you need two listeners.

Comment: I wanted to respond differently depending on whether the peer is IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're incompatible protocols, you have to map IPv4 to IPv6.

IPv6 isn't backwards compatible, but there's special representation for IPv4 mapped to IPv6.

80 bits set to 0 followed by 16 bits set to 1 followed by 32 bits that are the IPv4 address.

In other words, you can check if its ipv4 mapped to ipv6 like this:

```
fn is_mapped_to_ipv6(addr: SocketAddr) -> bool {
    match addr {
        SocketAddr::V6(v6) => match v6.ip().segments() {
            // 5 * 16 `0` bits, 16 `1` bits, leftover is actual IPv4 addr
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFFFF, ..] => true,
            _ => false,
        },
        _ => false,
    }
}
```